# Webview don't load css on Android Pie

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm create app on webview, webview load local html and style on link

Css load on android 4-8, but on android 9 css not load

Code:

```
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
data.append("<HTML><HEAD><LINK href=\"http://example.com/style.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/></HEAD><body>");
data.append(bundle.getString("content"));
data.append("</body></HTML>");

webView.loadData(data.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this add manifest

```
android:cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"
```

android 9 network security for this was passed. read this: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

or

```
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```